# Inherit page layout when converting LaTeX to HTML

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I use tex4ht but Im open to other suggestions.
So tex4ht documentation [tells](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/faq/LATEX/htch4.htm#x5-860004.17) how you can set the margins by yourself, but nothing about inheriting them from the LaTeX document. By default there are no margins at all. Is there maybe a config option to set them automatically as they are in an generated PDF?

Comment: No idea if some converter is able  to fix margins in HTML outputs, but generally this is undesirable for  web pages, so I guess that developers of converter  haven't bothered too much with this issue.

Comment: You might want to try [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX) --  it's probably not what you need, but it's impressive and fun . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't want (and cannot have) the same margins in your rendered HTML page as in PDF. You have fixed page size in PDF, but HTML can be displayed on 27 inch display, as well as on smartphone, and each of these devices needs different size of fonts and page margins.

TeX4ht don't set default page and font size, to allow you to use custom CSS styles that set them.

You can set CSS in a [configuration file](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#configurations1). Sample configuration file that implements some CSS readability tips from [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/css-techniques-legibility/), could look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{
  max-width:70ch;margin: 1rem auto;
  font-size-adjust:0.5;
}}
% trick from https://kittygiraudel.com/2020/05/18/using-calc-to-figure-out-optimal-ine-height/
\Css{html *{ line-height: calc(2px + 2ex + 2px); }}
\Css{p { 
    width: 100\%;
    max-width: 70ch;
    text-align: justify;
    hyphens: auto;}}
% fix for figures
\Css{figure p{text-align: center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important command here is `\Css`, which can insert shorter CSS snippets to the CSS file generated by TeX4ht.

Compile your file using

```
make4ht -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

This changes the look from this default:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The change is that the lines shouldn't be longer than 70 characters, the space between lines is a bit longer, and text justification and hypnenation is enabled.

If you want to change more elements of the design, you will probably want to use external CSS file. To add CSS file that is saved alongside your HTML documents, you can use the `\Configure{AddCss}` command:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{AddCss}{style.css}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You can also use CSS file that is hosted on some other site, for example some CSS framework on CDN. The following configuration file uses the [LaTeX.css](https://github.com/vincentdoerig/latex-css) project, which tries to mimic the default LaTeX look in HTML:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://latex.now.sh/style.min.css" />}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{@HEAD}` command can add code to HTML `<head>` element, where links to CSS files should be placed. The `\HCode` command is used to insert HTML tags. I've copied the `<link ...>` tag from LaTeX.css's site. One downside of this method is that you rely on availability of the referenced CSS file on someone else's machine. They can remove it, or update it in some non-compatible way, and your design will be broken. On the positive side, this method is easiest.

This is a sample page with LaTeX.css:

[image]

To find more suitable CSS files that you can use, search for [classles CSS frameworks](https://github.com/dbohdan/classless-css)

Comment: What I needed was to convert it to html, edit it by inserting some HTML data and then make an A4-sized PDF, that will look like directlu compiled one as much as possible, that's why margins were what I needed. But I understand that those technologies are built for different stuff and it's actually a part of my research and I needed proofs why acting as I described in the first sentence is a bad idea:) Thanks for the detailed response!